# Form Submission using JQuery & ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, form-submit

I have been working on this code

```
$("#library").submit(function(e){
    //return false;
    e.preventDefault();
    dataString = $("#library").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?= base_url() ?>index.php/library/comment",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $("#librarycomment").val("");
            $('#comment-list').prepend('<li><div class="avatar"><img src="<?= base_url();?>asset/css/library/images/picture.jpg">' +
                                       '</div>' + '<div class="colset">' + '<div class="author">' + data.user + 
                                       '&nbsp;<strong>' + data.date + '</strong>' +
                                       '</div>' + '<div class="comment-content">' +
                                       data.text + '</div></div></li>').find("li:first").hide().slideDown('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Where i would like to have a nice form validation without having to refresh the browser. Somewhat the code above does not work.

I have tried to replace e.preventDefault(); with

- e.stopPropagation
- return false

All giving nothing at all. The form does submit the data and store the data to the database. However, the ajax part does not run quiet like what i expect it to be.

Does anyone know what am i missing here?

Comment: Can you put the return false or preventdefault in the success function ?

Comment: hi FC thanks for replying. It still doesn't work even if i put those in the success. However, i found a work around by changing from .submit() to a .click(). Obviously i have to change my form as well to <form action='#' name='formName'> and create a button (instead of submit button).

Comment: I don't know if it's a better way, with only click the user can't submit with the 'Enter' key, it's bad for accessibility. Maybe replace click by on('submit'...).

Answer (score 0):

```
class somehelperclass
{
    public function unserialize($input, $pIndex = 'data')
    {
        if(!isset($input[$pIndex]))
            exit('index '.$pIndex.' is not exist');
        parse_str($input[$pIndex], $input);
        $post = array();
        foreach($input as $index => $value)
        {
            $index = preg_replace('/\;/', '', $index);
            $post[$index] = $value;
        }
        return $input;
    }

    public function jsonResponse($array)
    {
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($array);
        exit();
    }
}

// your controller

class Library extends CI_Controller
{
    public function comment()
    {
        $this->load->library('somehelperclass');
        $_POST = $this->somehelperclass->unserialize($_POST, 'data');
        $this->somehelperclass->jsonResponse($_POST);
    }
}

// js

$("#library").submit(function(){
    that = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/index.php/library/comment",
        data: {data: that.serialize()},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response)
        {
            $("#librarycomment").val("");
            $('#comment-list').prepend('<li><div class="avatar"><img' 
            + ' src="/asset/css/library/images/picture.jpg"></div>' 
            + '<div class="colset"><div class="author">' 
            + response.user + '&nbsp;<strong>' + response.date + '</strong>' +
           '</div>' + '<div class="comment-content">' +
           response.text + '</div></div></li>').find("li:first").hide().slideDown('slow');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```